# jQuery ui 1.7.3 datepicker set selected date + 3 days

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

How can I set a selected date of the jquery datepicker by adding 3 days to the actual date?

Like from 11/01/2011 to 11/04/2011

My current code doesn't work!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {$("#datepicker").datepicker();});
        //Set DatePicker to actual date + 3 days
        $('#dateselector').datepicker("setDate", new Date(date.getMonth()+"/"+(date.getDate()+3)+"/"+date.getFullYear()) );                      
</script>
```

Comment: Can you share full codes via jsfiddle.net ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker("setDate", "+3");
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/EryYr/1/

Quote from documentation:

> setDate
>   `.datepicker( "setDate" , date )`
>   ... The new date may be a Date object or a string in the
>   current date format (e.g. '01/26/2009'), **a number of days from today**
>   (e.g. +7) or a string of values and periods ('y' for years, 'm' for
>   months, 'w' for weeks, 'd' for days, e.g. '+1m +7d'), or null to clear
>   the selected date.

Comment: Do you also know how I can change the format to "dd.mm.yyyy"?

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-dateFormat

`$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy' });` should do this work

Comment: I have to done it on this way, but it doesn't work!      $(function() {
         $("#datepicker").datepicker();
         $('#datepicker').datepicker("setDate", "+3");
         $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy' });
        });

Comment: You didn't read the documentation. Call method `setDate` after datepicker initialization: `$('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy' }); $('#datepicker').datepicker("setDate", "+3");`

Comment: I read the documentation well, but on this way is also doesn't work! I also made a new [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150518/cannot-change-date-format-for-set-date-jquery-datepicker)